# Is it possible to surround a link with quotes in Asciidoctor?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm trying to surround a link with quotes when using Asciidoctor and I can't get it to work. It either includes the quotes in the link:

```
http://link.to.something["Title"]
```

Or it renders the raw text:

```
"http://link.to.something[Title]"
```

Does anyone know the syntax so it can render like the followin (HTML version)?

```
"<a href="http://link.to.something">Title</a>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where the `link:` macro prefix is needed.

```
"link:http://link.to.something[Title]"
```

You can think of the `link:` macro prefix as a way to force a link. It's kind of like an unconstrained link. It has stronger precedence than the `http:` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

If you put smart quotes around the link, then the `link:` macro prefix is not needed.

```
"`link:http://link.to.something[Title]`"
```

Comment: This works for HTML, but not PDF. I'm using: `gem 'asciidoctor-pdf', github: 'asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf', ref: '03ceac32e426421ebd6ef2499a14f5aac40ec47b'`. I'll try your other suggestion with link:

Comment: Using `"link:http://link.to.something[Title]"` works for both HTML and PDF.

Comment: Update, the syntax you show in your answer works in everything and does the curly quotes. So your note about `link:` not being needed is incorrect.